# How to prevent focus going to whole ListViewItem when the item's content view is clicked

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, focus, listviewitem, contentview

I have created a Xamarin ListView sample with customized item template.
When I clicked the content view in the item template focus is applied for the list view item instead of that content view in item template.

How to restrict the focus for the parent when the content view is clicked?

Comment: As you've discovered, a ListView tends to grab the click for itself. Try using a CollectionView instead.

Comment: Have you tried to use the tap event for the ListView ViewCell?  `<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Tapped="ViewCell_Tapped">                        
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>`